# Trigonometric identity proof problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My problem is from Israel Gelfand's Trigonometry textbook.

> *Page 48. Exercise 5:* d) $\frac{\sin\alpha}{1+\cos\alpha}=\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$

I would appreciate some hints on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Do you know about using "conjugate factors"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\sin^2\alpha = 1 - \cos^2\alpha$ and the latter expression is a difference of two squares.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but could not progress, I will try it again and tell you my result. Thank you.

Comment: I got the answer, thank you, looks like I just needed to follow my guess, instead of giving it up.

Comment: On the right side, multiply by $\frac{1 + \cos \alpha}{1 + \cos \alpha}$.